# How do you mint and burn ERC20 smart contract token using ink?

Tags: ink

I already have a running erc20 smart contract using ink.  I want to add mint and burn functions.  Can anyone point me to the right direction, e.g., sample code, etc.

Comment: May be worthwhile to look at PSP22, specifically: https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/PSP22/Extensions/mintable and examples: https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/tree/main/examples/psp22_extensions

Comment: You can also look at the OpenZepplin interface for the functions: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-_mint-address-uint256-

Answer (score 3):

In terms of ink! you could take a look at the OpenBrush reference implementation for [PSP-22](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-22.md) implementation. This is a standard akin to ERC-20, but for `pallet-contracts` and ink!.

There is an implementation of this standard in the OpenBrush project [here](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/token/psp22/psp22.rs).

Documentation on the mint and burn functionality can be found here:

- https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/PSP22/Extensions/mintable
- https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/PSP22/Extensions/burnable